# MYSQL and PHP update events?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I currently have an application that is checking the database for updates every 5 seconds. Although this is doing the job for the < 500 users , it doesn't seem very practical going ahead.

Is there any way to prod php when a row has been changed in the database? i know there are certain services to use but they are expensive or impractical for me to integrate at this time.

Is there a way to do this using triggers in MYSQL or am i worrying about nothing if say, 10,000 users where to query the database every 5 seconds?

Thanks for your time

Comment: It depends on what you're wanting to trigger exactly, but a five-second poll sounds reasonable to me. Instant enough without being a hammer on the server. Bonus points if you wrap the poll in a `requestAnimationFrame` call, because then it will *only* reload if the browser tab is visible - my users have commented positively on updates being delayed until the tab is in focus again, as it lets them *see* the change.

Comment: Well the users location is inserted into the database every 5 seconds and a web application selects the location data every 5 seconds, i guess that's 2 requests per user, per 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Note

If you're worried about the cost of calling the MySQL server every 5 seconds, [PHP supports persistent connections to the database](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php). This will improve execution speed, without changing your script (or mechanism of notification) too much, and might be enough.

---

> Is there any way to prod php when a row has been changed in the
>   database?

You seem to want to trigger some kind of **push mechanism** initiated by MySQL. Out of the box, that is not possible without some kind of plugin or middleware.

### Middleware

There are a couple of free daemons available that keep a persistent connection to the MySQL Server and pool the database within the specified interval. This emulates a PUSH mechanism.
You can also create one yourself. [This guy created an example using NodeJS](http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/) but you can use PHP to accomplish the same results.

This is probably the best way to tackle the problem, albeit not being a TRUE push notification system.

### Plugin

It is also possible to initiate the notification within MySQL.

1. [MySQL >= 5.1.6 has scheduled events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html). You can schedule an event to trigger every time interval to look for changes in the database.
2. You can run system commands through MySQL with a plugin called [lib_mysqludf_sys](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys)

Basically you would use the MySQL scheduled event to look for changes in a table and if the changes are found, it will execute a command.
That command can be a PHP script that, in turn, notifies your client of those changes.

The client can be notified through a Pooling (as you're doing right now) or through PUSH notifications (using websockets). [PHP supports websockets](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.sockets.php) and [most recent browsers support do too.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)

Comment: Thanks very much for your time, that's exactly what I was looking for - I will explore the best option for my app. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any way to prod php when a row has been changed in the database?
No. PHP files are executed once and the output is dumped out.

To have this kind of functionality you can use PHP, and have an ajax request update the browser for the user, at a predefined interval or on demand with a button control.

If you want to push updates from the database to the web client, you can look at using [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) which connects to a socket server and allows you to push events. If scalability is a concern, I would also recommend looking at Node.JS, you will get some additional performance on your current hardware. It is also much easier to scale your application.

Comment: just because something is supported does not mean that it is recommended. I can write an OS in PHP doesn't make it a good idea.